# MAAS can't deploy Ubuntu Server due to missing boot kernel

Tags: maas

I can PXE boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS with my new MAAS 12.10 server.

If I change the default deployment distro to 12.10 I get a tftp boot error that is complaing that the boot kernel can't be found ?

Does the maas-import-pxe-files import all the required files for 12.10 server deployment or is there something extra that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, maas-import-pxe-files should download all these files, for the Ubuntu releases listed in `/etc/maas/import_pxe_files`.

So edit that file and make sure the setting for RELEASES includes quantal!  Then run the import script again, and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I ran into this same problem yesterday. The import_pxe_files script specifies that only precise is downloaded. There is a commented-out line above it that specifies oneiric and precise, but using it as a model to change to precise and quantal (to match the selection boxes in the MAAS web interface) results in a failure of import_pxe_files to download the quantal bits. The URLs that import_pxe_files uses to fetch the quantal images are not valid. They seem to be well formed, but the files don't exist at those locations.